# WPF TextBox Binding Validation Rules not Firing on LostFocus When TextBox is Empty

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox

We all know how sucky WPF validation is out of the box. I am trying a very simple thing and for some reason it is always failing. I have a TextBox and my only requirement is to validate that the user inputs something in the TextBox. The TextBox is bound to a Customer object with FirstName and LastName properties.

Here is the XAML code:

```
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="0" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="FirstName" >
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <ExceptionValidationRule />
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>

            </TextBox>
```

Here is the Customer class FirstName property:

```
public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName;}
            set
            {
                if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    throw new ApplicationException("FirstName cannot be null or empty!");
                _firstName = value; 

                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
```

Even though I am throwing an exception if the FirstName (value) is null or empty it is only handled if I type something in the TextBox and then delete it and then tab off. The reason is that it is dependent on the property changed event. But even if I put that TextBox binding on Focus it does not fire the validation.

UPDATE:

One of the ugliest ways to handle this issue is to assign the String.Empty to the TextBoxes on the Window.Loaded event:

```
 void AddCustomerWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get all the textboxes and set the property to empty strings! 

            txtFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
            txtLastName.Text = String.Empty; 
        }
```

Here is the code for binding:

```
 public AddCustomerWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(AddCustomerWindow_Loaded);

            gvAddCustomer.DataContext = new Customer();  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I use is to wire-up the controls to update their own binding sources whenever they lose focus.  This makes the controls validate after the user has tabbed or clicked through them once.

```
public AddCustomerWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += AddCustomerWindow_Loaded;
    gvAddCustomer.DataContext = new Customer();  
}

void AddCustomerWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Manually wire up textboxes of specific interest.
    UpdateSourceOnLostFocus(new TextBox[] {txtFirstName, txtLastName},
                            TextBox.TextProperty);

    // Or, wire up ALL controls of a given type with the help of Telerik's
    // ChildrenOfType extension, using Linq to filter the list where appropriate.
    UpdateSourceOnLostFocus(this.ChildrenOfType<RadDatePicker>()
                                .Where(picker => !picker.IsReadOnly), 
                            RadDatePicker.SelectedValueProperty);
}

void UpdateSourceOnLostFocus<T>(IEnumerable<T> controls, DependencyProperty prop) where T : Control
{
    controls.ToList()
        .ForEach(ctrl =>
        {
            var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(ctrl, prop);
            if (binding != null)
                ctrl.LostFocus += (sender, args) => binding.UpdateSource();
        });
}
```

If you also want the controls to validate on load - i.e., *before* the user tabs/clicks through them - then you could write an UpdateSourceNow method similar to the one above, and call it from AddCustomerWindow_Loaded instead.

However, I prefer to wait until each control is visited, because it can be somewhat alarming to users if they immediately see a screen full of red boxes when they want to enter a new Model object instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example XAML code, I don't see any Binding. I presume the Text property of the TextBox is bound to FirstName?

Secondly: is FirstName initialized at first, or does it return `null` when retrieved by the TextBox? Binding to a `null` value always gives strange behaviors...

Try saying this in the property:

```
   public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            if (_firstName == null)
            {
                _firstName = String.Empty;
            }
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                throw new ApplicationException("FirstName cannot be null or empty!");
            _firstName = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As, you can see the updated code the TextBox is bound to a new Customer object. When I type nothing in the TextBox and Tab to a different control nothing happens. It should fire the validation but it does not! The only way to fire the validation is if I manually assign the .Text property of TextBox in the Window.Loaded event.

Comment: Yes, I see. And when the FirstName is called, does it return a String or a null value?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to specify the UpdateSourceTrigger and you should be good to go (note: I also usually add the ValidatesOnDataErrors=true):

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to set all the values at the start, or use the if statement you could set a private variable initially:

```
private string _FirstName = String.Empty;
public string FirstName
{
    get { return _FirstName; }
    set
    {
        // Probably check for null and handle it here first
        _FirstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INotifyDataError interface to manage validation.

Some useful links:

http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/
http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/09/18/wpf-4-5-asynchronous-data-validation/